# How to access SSH from web without connecting from client

Tags: java

I have a server which is behind a firewall and the SSH port is disabled.

I want to access via SSH to monitor services on a server. My web server is Apache Tomcat. How can I achieve this? is there any java application for this?

Comment: are you talking about ssh over http?

Comment: @Dmitry  yes i am talking ssh over http

Comment: @talnicolas hi i am seroiously working on my english , and accepting answers on stack over flow.

Comment: ok, in that case what are you hoping to get out of SO answers that you can't just from googling "applications for ssh over http"?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 Solutions(which you may combine together too!):

1. **Web-Terminals**:There are many "web based terminals" written in different languages, i'm not sure which one simply runs on Apache Tomcat, but i'm sure there are some written in Java like WebTerm or JCTerm.
2. **Tunnels**: You could also try "TCP over HTTP Tunnels".

I believe a good way to start is to take a look at [this](http://anyterm.org/compared.html) comparison of these Tools by AnyTerm.